# Trying to reverse an output in Python

Tags: python, reverse

So I'm trying to reverse an output in Python but I don't know how to. I tried looking up solutions online, but they haven't worked at all. Here's the piece of code I need to reverse (particularly the last line).

```
# FIXME (2): Output the four values in reverse

user_integer = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))
user_float = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
user_character = input('Enter character:\n')
user_string = input('Enter string:\n')
print(user_integer, user_float, user_character, user_string, '\n')
```

Comment: Reverse what, exactly? Given your current code, just manually reverse the arguments to `print`

Comment: @roganjosh This is the code I need reversed: `print(user_integer, user_float, user_character, user_string, '\n')`

Answer (score -1):

You can reverse any iterable that supports slices like so:

```
Python 3.8.0 (default, Dec  3 2019, 17:33:19)
[GCC 9.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> mystring = "foobarbaz"
>>> mystring[::-1]
zabraboof
>>>
```

There is an explanation of slice notation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation).

Edit: If the iterable does not support slices then you can still use the `reversed` built-in. For simplicity I will demonstrate with a string, although you will usually want to use the method I described above when manipulating strings.

```
Python 3.8.0 (default, Dec  3 2019, 17:33:19)
[GCC 9.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> mystring = "foobarbaz"
>>> ''.join(reversed(mystring))
'zabraboof'
>>>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question because they have multiple arguments going to `print`

Comment: To be honest, since I'm not sure exactly what is needed, I was answering the question as asked in the title. I agree with your comments that the OP's problem statement is not well formed enough to give me any special confidence that this will or will not solve their problem.

Answer (score -1):

three years later and I'm going to just post the full answer to the question because I took the same course. This is for all future students, you're welcome!

```
# FIXME (1): Finish reading other items into variables, then output the four values on a single line separated by a space
user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))
user_flo = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
user_cha = input('Enter character:\n')
user_str = input('Enter string:\n')  

print(user_int, user_flo, user_cha, user_str)



# FIXME (2): Output the four values in reverse

print(user_str, user_cha, user_flo, user_int)



# FIXME (3): Convert the integer to a character, and output that character

print(user_int, 'converted to a character is', chr(user_int))
```